# Proving ${\det}(A) = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if a row or column of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ consists of entirely zeros, then ${\det}(A)=0$.

I know the definition of determinant and how to calculate the determinant for any $n\times n$ matrix. I'm just somewhat lost on how to bring what I know into a generic proof for any matrix that is $n\times n$.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which definition of determinant are you using?

Comment: See [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Square_Matrix_with_Duplicate_Rows_has_Zero_Determinant).

Comment: You say that you know how to calculate the determinant, but there are quite a few techniques, so it's not clear what you mean — and so it's not clear how to help you use your knowledge, as you've asked.  If you had a particular, say, $7\times 7$ matrix with a zero row in front of you, what would you do to calculate its determinant?

Comment: I am using the definition: The determinant is a function that assigns to every
square (must be square!) matrix A a number
det A
so that
• det A 6= 0 ⇐⇒ A is invertible.,
• det(AB) = det A · det B,
• det A is related to volume in a way explained below.

Answer (score 2):

The trivial case is when $A$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix.

For $n\times n$ matrix $A$, where $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to 2, we can use cofactor expansion in a particular row (or column) to find $\det(A)$. The following link is useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29. The section on "Applications of minors and cofactors" is quite useful.

Now, suppose that the $i$th row consists entirely of $0$s. We choose this row for finding $\det(A)$ using expansion by cofactors. Then, $\det(A)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}C_{ij}=0$ because $a_{ij}=0$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Similarly, suppose that the $j$th column consists entirely of $0$s. We choose this column for finding $\det(A)$ using expansion by cofactors. Then, $\det(A)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}C_{ij}=0$ because $a_{ij}=0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 1):

You mention in comments that you know $\det(A)=0$ iff $A$ is uninvertible.  To show $A$ is uninvertible if it has a zero row, find $b$ such that $Ax=b$ has no solution.  To show $A$ is uninvertible if $A$ has a zero column, find nonzero $x$ such that $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Use contradiction. suppose that the matrix $A_{n\times n}$ have a row or column that consists of entirely zeros and $\det(A)\neq0$ then, there is  $A^{-1}$ such that:
$$A\cdot A^{-1}=I_{n\times n}$$

but this not is possible.

Comment: I think contradiction is a *little* bit awkward here. I feel like contrapositive is slicker in this instance but philosophically they're the same argument.

Comment: I refer to negation of a implication; $\neg(p\rightarrow q)\equiv p \wedge \neg q$